# Metodo PUT con vue.js y phalcon

Tags: vue.js, phalcon

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede explicar como envio un formulario pr medio de x-www-urlencoded en vue.js?
ya que el atributo **enctype** no me esta funcionando, y si envio el formulario con **formData()** este llega vacio al API.

Le agradeceria mucho a la persona que pueda explicar.

Comment: Con que libreria llamas al api? https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource pudes poner en el header 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: si lo hago con la libreria de vue-resource y ya intente lo que me dices pero no tampoco me funciona. Gracias

Comment: mira asi hago mi peticion
`const url = e.target.getAttribute('action')
      const payload = new FormData(e.target)

      this.$http.put(url, payload,{
        responseType: 'json',
        header: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.message)`

Comment: ´const url = e.target.getAttribute('action')
      const payload = new FormData(e.target)

      this.$http.put(url, payload,{
        responseType: 'json',
        header: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.message)´

Comment: y en la api que error tienes? No puedes leerlo?

Comment: el Api esta perfecto el error es de vue.js, no se si este framework no permite utilizar verbos PUT y DELETE.

Comment: No estas llamando bien:
this.$http.put(url, payload,{ header: { 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }) y cuando haces la llamada llega a la api o ni siquiera llega?

Comment: El api me retorna los errores que debe mostrar cuando el formulario esta vacio.
Testeo mi Api con Postman y todo lo hace bien, por eso te digo que no se si es problema de Vue.js

Comment: si pasas por consola el payload es igual a como lo envias en postman?

Comment: Podrias por favor agregar toda la informacion que esta en los comentarios dentro de la pregunta? usa el boton [edit]

Comment: Disculpa no entiendo tu pregunta :(

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando la librería [github.com/pagekit/vue-resource](http://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource) :

Para enviar la información con el tipo de content que dices:

```js
var url = "http://urlatuapi.com";
var datos = {a : 1, b: 2};
this.$http.put(url, datos, { header: { 
                               'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                           }
 }).then(function(){});
```